# xpages update multivalue field to mail sender, cannot send to multiple user

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Field Dep_rev contain of

[image]

I only manage to using xpages JavaScript to send one user only.

method : **maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo",document1.getItemValueString("Dep_rev"));**

Below is my coding

```
var maildoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Testing mail");
session.setConvertMime(false);
var stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText("<html><body>");



stream.writeText("<p>Testing</p>");

stream.writeText("</body></html>");
var body = maildoc.createMIMEEntity("Body");
body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 1725);
stream.close();
maildoc.closeMIMEEntities(true);
session.setConvertMime(true);

maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo",document1.getItemValueString("Dep_rev"));     
maildoc.send();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `getItemValue`:

```
maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo",document1.getItemValue("Dep_rev"));
```

As an alternative you can use `copyItem`:

```
maildoc.copyItem(document1.getDocument().getFirstItem("Dep_rev"), "SendTo");
```